# Spring inject xml values to properties-config.xml then to a bean

Tags: sql, xml, spring, dependency-injection

I am a noob at Spring, but have not find any material based on this type of injection.

Having a **Queries.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="sql.accountdao.select">
    </entry>

    <entry key="sql.accountdao.insert"> 
    </entry>
</properties>
```

Also have a **properties-config.xml**, which is containg the queries.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <array>
                <value>classpath:sql/Queries.xml</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And naturally have a dao-config.xml, where I want to reference the Queries.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="namedParamTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Either annotations or xml will be correct -->
    <bean id="accountDao" class="dao.impl.AccountDAOImpl">
    <property name="namedParameterJdbcTemplate" ref="namedParamTemplate" />
        <property name="insertSQL" ????? />
        <property name="selectSQL" ???? />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Tried this way also in the **AccountDAOImpl**.java:

```
public class AccountDAOImpl implements AccountDAO {

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Value("${sql.accountdao.select}")
    private String selectSql;

    @Value("${sql.accountdao.insert}")
    private String insertSql;

    @Required
    public void setSelectSql(String selectSql) {
        this.selectSql = selectSql;
    }

    @Required
    public void setInsertSql(String insertSql) {
        this.insertSql = insertSql;
    }
```

...

Annotation based injection just did not work.
Have any idea anybody?

Both of them are in the classpath @ web.xml.

**Exception**:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDao' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/root/dao-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Properties 'insertSql' and 'selectSql' are required for bean 'accountDao'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, simple ${} at the **config-dao.xml**:

```
<property name="insertSql" value="${sql.accountdao.insert}" />
<property name="selectSql" value="${sql.accountdao.select}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

in web.xml must be declared this xml files:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/[Your DIR]/[Your XMLFiles].xml 
        </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: <param-value>
            classpath:META-INF/spring/root/dao-config.xml
            classpath:META-INF/spring/root/database-config.xml
            classpath:META-INF/spring/root/properties-config.xml
        </param-value>

properties-config.xml is at the classpath, I think it is enough, but tried with yours same exception.

Comment: but I appreciate your efforts and give you a thumb up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in spring is tow type of injection.
you use setter injection of two way.
in Setter Injection must be setter method of injected object.
Then AccountDAOImpl  must be added the following method:

```
public void setNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate  namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {
this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
}
```

i hope to help you.

Comment: You have right, but I already have it in my code just cut out the irrevelant part.

Comment: what raised error when you deploy your application?